# use chez scheme to execute current s-expression

Tags: scheme, chez-scheme

I want to pass the current line of s-expression to scheme interpreter and execute it , how should I do ?

I use Chez Scheme Petite as the interpreter , however , if I pass a file to it , it just sets up the environment , I just want to pass the code to it and run the code and get the results printed .

For example , I have such code

```
(define fact    
  (lambda (n)    
    (cond ((= n 1) 1)    
      (else (* n (fact (- n 1)))))))    

(fact 5)
```

and save it as fact.ss ;

If I run it in cmd , petite fact.ss , I can only set up the environment , I need to reenter (fact 5) after ">" , then get the result print .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *are* executing it. However, since you're doing nothing with the return value of `(fact 5)`, it just gets thrown away.

Perhaps you should try `(display (fact 5))` instead.